# Joi validate Sum across an Array

Tags: javascript, validation, joi

I want to validate a given JSON , the constrain being `expenditure` must not exceed `credit`

```
{
  "expenditure": {
    "house": 2,
    "electricity": 1,
    "phone": 12
  },
  "credit": 6
}
```

```
const Joi = require("joi");

const schema = Joi.object({

    expenditure: Joi.object({
        house: Joi.number().integer().min(0).max(5).optional(),
        electricity: Joi.number().integer().min(0).max(5).optional(),
        phone: Joi.number().integer().min(0).max(5).optional()
    }),

    credit: Joi.number().integer().min(0).max(15).greater(
        Joi.ref('expenditure', {"adjust": expenditure => {
            return expenditure.house + expenditure.electricity + expenditure.phone;
        }})
    )
});
```

Above code works fine for constraining within an object scope but I need to do validation of something this sorts

```
[
    {
        "phone_allowance": 12
    },
    {
        "phone_allowance": 10
    },
]
```

To make sure sum of all `phone_allowance` in the array never exceeds some given value say `50`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `custom()`

https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/master/API.md#anycustommethod-description

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-ggynfw?file=index.js)**

```
var schema = Joi.array().items(
  Joi.object({
    phone_allowance: Joi.number()
  })
).custom((value, helpers) => {
  var total = value.reduce((a, b) => a + b.phone_allowance, 0)

  if (total > 5) {
    return helpers.error('any.invalid');
  }

  return value;
});
```